# rspec: error on attribute (which exists) not found

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, state-machine

I've got some problems specing a validation of my model, which acts as a state machine (gem state_machine 0.9.4). Via the stat_machine, I defined a validation for bikes in the state delivered:

```
state :delivered do
  validates_presence_of :shipping_number
end
```

in my specs this works right:

```
it "may not transit to :delivered without a shipping number " do
  @bike.state = 'delivered'
  @bike.shipping_number = nil
  @bike.save
  @bike.should have(1).error_on(:shipping_number)
end
```

but when specing like this:

```
it "may not transit to :delivered without a shipping number " do
  @bike.shipping_number = nil
  @bike.deliver
  @bike.should have(1).error_on(:shipping_number)
end
```

I get:

```
expected 1 error on :shipping_number, got 0
```

even though

```
it "may not transit to :delivered without a shipping number " do
  @bike.shipping_number = nil
  @bike.deliver
  raise @bike.errors.inspect
end
```

shows me:

```
Failure/Error: raise @bike.errors.inspect
#<OrderedHash {:shipping_number=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

can somebody explain that?

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link here, it explains the issue:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130202082209/http://agaskar.com/post/1627270986/fun-state-machine-rspec-gotcha

Bottom line: failed state transition causes a rollback to the previous state, and now the validates_presence_of is not relevant for the following check of errors.

Though there's probably a more idiomatic way to do it, I did something like this in the spec:

```
@bike.errors.include?(:shipping_number).should == true
```