# rspec shoulda syntax for model.errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I get the following error message for the code below:

```
 Failure/Error: @league.errors.on(:short_name).should_equal "can't be blank"
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `on' for #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000001017853f0>


@league.errors.on(:short_name).should_equal "can't be blank"
```

According to several documentation references that I am reading, this should work.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759196/rspec-error-on-attribute-which-exists-not-found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759196/rspec-error-on-attribute-which-exists-not-found)

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately, that question was never answered it seems (or at least accepted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `@location.errors` is a hash:

```
require 'rspec'

describe "Location" do
  before(:each) do
    @location = double("Location")
    @location.stub(:errors).and_return(:short_name => "can't be blank")
  end

  it "should work like a hash" do
    @location.errors[:short_name].should == "can't be blank"
  end
end
```